# Python Aggregation without PANDAS

Tags: python, loops, aggregation

I have a sorted and nested list. Each element in the list has 3 sub-elements; 'Drugname', Doctor_id, Amount. For a given drugname (which repeats) the doctor ids are different and so are the amounts. See sample list below..

I need an output where, for each drugname, I need to count the total UNIQUE doctor ids and the sum of the dollar amount for that drug. For ex, for the list snippet below..

```
[
   ['CIPROFLOXACIN HCL', 1801093968, 61.49],
   ['CIPROFLOXACIN HCL', 1588763981, 445.23],
   ['HYDROCODONE-ACETAMINOPHEN', 1801093968, 251.52],
   ['HYDROCODONE-ACETAMINOPHEN', 1588763981, 263.16],
   ['HYDROXYZINE HCL', 1952310666, 945.5],
   ['IBUPROFEN', 1801093968, 67.06],
   ['INVEGA SUSTENNA', 1952310666, 75345.68]
]
```

The desired output is as below.

```
[
   ['CIPROFLOXACIN HCL', 2, 516.72],
   ['HYDROCODONE-ACETAMINOPHEN', 2, 514.68]
   ['HYDROXYZINE HCL', 1, 945.5]
   ['IBUPROFEN', 1, 67.06]
   ['INVEGA SUSTENNA', 1, 75345.68]
]
```

In a database world this is the easiest thing with a simple GROUP BY on drugname. In Python, I am not allowed to use PANDAS, NumPy etc. Just the basic building blocks of Python. I tried the below code but I am unable to reset the count variable to count doctor ids and amounts. This commented code is one of several attempts. Not sure if I need to use a nested for loop or a for loop-while loop combo.

All help is appreciated!

```
aggr_list = []
temp_drug_name = ''
doc_count = 0
amount = 0
for list_element in sorted_new_list:
    temp_drug_name = list_element[0]
    if temp_drug_name == list_element[0]:
        amount += float(amount)
        doc_count += 1

    aggr_list.append([temp_drug_name, doc_count, amount])

print(aggr_list)
```

Comment: A rather large hint: you need a dictionary.

Comment: The dollar amount for the second element is incorrect as shown. It should be 251.52 + 263.16 = 514.68

Comment: @DanielRoseman No you don't need a dictionary since the OP states that the given list is already sorted.

Comment: hmmm...not sure how a dictionary would do the trick. The key in the dict, being unique, the dict would not hold the repeating drugname, right? Unless it is used to store the final product i guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the list is already sorted you can simply iterate through the list (named `l` in the example below) and keep track of the name of the last iteration, and if the name of the current iteration is different from the last, insert a new entry to the output. Use a set to keep track of the doctor IDs already seen for the current drug, and only increment the the second item of the last entry of the output by 1 if the doctor ID is not seen. And increment the third item of the last entry of the output by the amount of the current iteration:

```
output = []
last = None
for name, id, amount in l:
    if name != last:
        output.append([name, 0, 0])
        last = name
        ids = set()
    if id not in ids:
        output[-1][1] += 1
        ids.add(id)
    output[-1][2] += amount
```

`output` becomes:

```
[['CIPROFLOXACIN HCL', 2, 506.72],
 ['HYDROCODONE-ACETAMINOPHEN', 2, 514.6800000000001],
 ['HYDROXYZINE HCL', 1, 945.5],
 ['IBUPROFEN', 1, 67.06],
 ['INVEGA SUSTENNA', 1, 75345.68]]
```

Note that decimal floating points are approximated in the binary system that the computer uses (please read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)), so some minor errors are inevitable as seen in the sum of the second entry above.

Comment: Whoa! I was not aware of the 'last' variable element of a list. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, after adding the set code, the results are not as expected.  It shows ['CIPROFLOXACIN HCL', 1, 506] and ['HYDROCODONE-ACETAMINOPHEN', 1, 515] for the two drugs that should have a doctor_id count of 2. In fact, for all the drugs, the doctor_id count is always showing 1. The previous iteration was giving the right results.

Comment: output = []
last = None
for name, id, amount in sorted_new_list:
    if name != last:
        output.append([name, 0, 0])
        last = name
        ids = set()
    if id not in ids:
        ids.add(id)
    output[-1][1] += 1
    output[-1][2] += amount    Made a little tweak to the above code. Now it works.

Comment: I don't see how my code wouldn't work. Please see a demo here: https://ideone.com/htRNXk Also, I don't see how your tweaked code is any different from mine. You simply swapped the execution of `output[-1][1] += 1` and `ids.add(id)`, in which the order does not matter.

Comment: Hi...I looked at the link you provided and for ['CIPROFLOXACIN HCL', 1801093968, 61.49],
   ['CIPROFLOXACIN HCL', 1588763981, 445.23],
   ['CIPROFLOXACIN HCL', 1588763981, 123], where you have three elements, the doctor_id shows as 2 in your stdout. My original set had two elements only for this drug as seen in my desired output snippet.

Comment: I added that extra entry just to show you that it only counts unique doctor IDs, which for `CIPROFLOXACIN HCL` is correctly 2. Feel free to remove that entry and re-run it.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I got the solution now. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a focus on readability, it doesn't consider that the entries in your original list are sorted by drug name.

It does one pass on all the entries of your data , then a pass on the number of unique drugs.

To do only a single pass on all the entries of your sorted data, see @blhsing solution

```py
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
Entry = namedtuple('Entry',['doctors', 'prices'])
processed_data = defaultdict(lambda: Entry(doctors=set(), prices=[]))

for entry in data:
    drug_name, doctor_id, price = entry
    processed_data[drug_name].doctors.add(doctor_id)
    processed_data[drug_name].prices.append(price)

stat_list = [[drug_name, len(entry.doctors), sum(entry.prices)] for drug_name, entry in processed_data.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Pandas or defaultdict:

```py
    d={}

    for row in l:

       if row[0] in d:
           d[row[0]].append(row[1])
           d[row[0]].append(row[2])
       else:
           d[row[0]]=[row[1]]
           d[row[0]].append(row[2])

    return [[key, len(set(val[0::2])), sum(val[1::2])] for key, val in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusable solution, meant for those who arrive here trough Google:

```
def group_by(rows, key):
    m = {}
    for row in rows:
        k = key(row)
        try:
            m[k].append(row)
        except KeyError:
            m[k] = [row]
    return m.values()


grouped_by_drug = group_by(data, key=lambda row: row[0])
result = [
    (
        drug_rows[0][0],
        len(drug_rows),
        sum(row[2] for row in drug_rows)
    )
    for drug_rows in grouped_by_drug
]
```

You can also use `defaultdict` in this implementation, which for my use case is slightly faster.